# Creating secondary virtual address for process memory

Tags: linux, memory-management

Is there a way to create a secondary virtual memory mapping for some region of a process' memory? I.e., give some memory (allocated on the heap or, if necessary via some other means), is there a user-level way to map that same memory at some other address (say, via mmap).

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? I assume you aren't looking for `memcpy()` from one area to another?

Comment: I am looking to get a second address for the memory location, i.e., a way to get a pointer p that points to the same (physical) memory as q such that p != q.

Comment: Like a symlink for memory? Can you give some idea of what you hope to accomplish with this? At the end of the day, memory is at a single address in a process' address space, unless you copy it?

Comment: I think I found the solution: use shmat twice to map the same shared memory into a process at two different addresses.

Comment: As for the reason:the purpose is in a processor simulation scenario where the simulated processor needs to map its address space onto the host address spaces. Using the secondary address space at a well-known prefix could be used to improve that address translation.